# today.getHours Não aceita valor 09:00

Tags: javascript, data

```
  public metodoCorte:any;

 if (today.getHours() >= this.metodoCorte) {
        this.errors.push('Horário de corte dos domingos (9h) atingido, favor escolher uma data posterior a atual.');
      }
```

`this.metodoCorte` tem o valor de 09:30, 16:00, horario padrão Brasileiro, como eu poderia usar ele para saber se já passou do horário de corte?

Comment: `9`  não é comparável com `'9:00'`.

Comment: Como eu poderia fazer essa validação com a hora 09 e os minutos 30 ?
Teria como ?

Comment: Se conseguir me mandar um exemplo de acordo com a minha função e os valores que eu tenho eu ficaria agradecido

Comment: Só pra confirmar, `metodoCorte` é uma string?

Comment: @hkotsubo Ele vem nesse formato 09:30, pode vir nesse também 16:00, ele é dinamico, pode vir em todos os horarios padrão br

Comment: Eu perguntei o **tipo** da variável, se é uma string

Comment: @hkotsubo Number, tentei como any também

Comment: Não pode ser. Se `metodoCorte` é um `Number`, não tem como o formato ser `09:30`, esse `:` não faz parte de nenhum tipo numérico (na verdade números nem "tem" formato de fato). A menos que sejam dois números, um para a hora e outro para o minuto. Sugiro [edit] a pergunta e colocar um [mcve] <-- leia este link, tem dicas de como deixar mais claro a pergunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<del>Combine a saída de `getHours()` com `getMinutes()` para criar uma string que você consiga comparar.</del>

Correção:
Na verdade o que você precisa é transformar `metodoCorte` em um número. Só assim você consegue comparar com outro número.

Mas você ainda precisa usar a função `getMinutes()`, porque, por exemplo se for 9:15, o `getHours()` vai retornar apenas `9` e a sessão vai expirar antes do tempo.

Se você fizer algo como:

```js
hora = today.getHours() * 100 + today.getMinutes()
```

A hora vai ser armazenada como `915`. Aí quando você comparar com o `metodoCorte`, ele também precisa estar nesse formato (`09:00` vira `900` e `16:30` vira `1630`).

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Como eu poderia fazer essa validação com a hora 09 e os minutos 30 ?
Teria como ? não consegui nem fazer a validação da hora com o getHours 09

Comment: Mudei para 
          if (today.getHours() *100 + today.getMinutes() >= this.metodoCorte) {
            this.errors.push('Horário de corte dos domingos', this.metodoCorte, 'atingido, favor escolher uma data posterior a atual.');
          }

Comment: Só não entendi como eu poderia converter o metodoCorte, ele esta como 09:00, ele é dinamico, pode estar como 09:30 também

Comment: Acho que assim funcionaria: ``temp = metodoCorte.split(":"); 
metodoCorteNumero = parseInt(temp[0],10) *100 + parseInt(temp[1],10)`` agora a variavel ``metodoCorteNumero`` é o número que você quer comparar

Comment: this.metodoCorte = this.metodoCorte.split(":");  this.metodoCorte = parseInt(this.metodoCorte[0],10) *100 + parseInt(this.metodoCorte[1],10)

Comment: Obrigado, sua resposta deu certo

Answer (score 1):

> Se `metodoCorte` "*está no formato 09:30*" como você diz, então provavelmente é uma string (um texto contendo os caracteres `0`, `9`, `:` etc). Entenda que números e datas/horários não têm formato. Eles só representam "conceitos": um número representa determinada quantidade, horários representam momentos específicos do dia. Os valores numéricos não possuem formato, embora possam ser representados de determinada forma (ou seja, `09:30` é apenas uma representação de um horário específico, assim como `9h30` ou `nove e meia` - os textos são diferentes, mas todos representam o mesmo instante).

Dito isso, se `metodoCorte` é uma string, primeiro separe as partes e converta-as para números. Depois compare-as com a data atual:

```js
let metodoCorte = '09:30';
let today = // uma data qualquer
let horaAtual = today.getHours();

// obtém a hora e o minuto da string
let [hora, minuto] = metodoCorte.split(':').map(v => parseInt(v));

// compara com a data atual
if (horaAtual > hora || (horaAtual == hora && today.getMinutes() > minuto)) {
    console.log('Já passou do horário de corte');
} else {
    console.log('Ainda não passou do horário de corte');
}
```

Estou assumindo que você só quer comparar o horário, sem levar em conta o dia (sem saber o contexto do código, não dá pra afirmar se está correto ou não).

Levando em conta apenas o horário, basta pensar o seguinte: se o horário de corte é 09:30, como eu sei se a hora atual está antes ou depois?

- primeiro eu vejo somente a hora: se for maior que 9, nem preciso olhar os minutos, pois já sei que passou do horário de corte
- se a hora atual for igual a 9, aí eu preciso olhar os minutos, e basta ver se o minuto atual é maior que o minuto do horário de corte
- se a hora atual for menor que 9, ele já cai no `else` direto, pois aí eu sei que não passou do horário de corte

Não precisa fazer contas mirabolantes, apenas comparações simples.